# Because I subtract days a DateTime to get a JSON?

Tags: c#

I do not understand why when I send the date in JSON format to my REST API it saves it correctly in MySQL, but when I want to obtain a DateTime record it subtracts a day or more according to the one I want.

I checked the JSON data with Postman to see that it is not a problem of MySQL or Node.js and the date is correct.
[image: MySQL]

[image: JSON]

**Class Ventas**

```
public class Venta
{
        // Others properties

        [JsonProperty("fecha")]
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

If the date is a string property then it works.

```
string fecha = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Parse(venta[0].Fecha));
```

Debug: 01/05/2018

But if the property is DateTime subtraction days.

```
DateTime fecha = venta[0].Fecha;
```

Debug: 30/04/2018 22:00:00

Comment: Have you checked time zones? Better save them in UTC

Comment: Looks like a timezone issue.  The one in your json is UTC and I bet your timezone is 2 hours off of that.

Comment: I have configure timezones in Node.js, mysql and phpmyadmin.

Comment: `DateTime` does not have extensive zones support, consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead. It might be that the JSON is parsed as a `DateTimeKind.UTC` while the database record is returned as `DateTimeKind.Local`. The `DateTime.Parse` may behave in a completely different manner with respect to `DateTimeKind`, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Returns)